# Отправить данные ввода c текстового поля через AJAX, живой поиск

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как адаптировать плагин живого поиска под ajax запрос/ответ?

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Другими словами, как отправить данные на сервер?

После отпраывки я планирую эти данные получить в .php файле, обработать, сделать выборку из бд и сформировать строку вида:

`{ label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },`

Затем вставить  в   `var data = []`

Или  может быть нужно как-то по-другому сделать?

Помогите пожалуйста с frontend для отправки получения данных для данного плагина! Спасибо!

Comment: и сформировать строку вида: - это называется JSON . В PHP например посмотри код $some = ['label'=>'annhhx10', 'category' => 'Products']; echo(json_encode($some)); die();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Тут](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)  немного больше примеров и на русском. И на сколько могу судить в примерах почти ваш случай. Удачи)
Вот пример кода на случай смены URL источника:)

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
    // организуем кроссдоменный запрос 
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      // параметры запроса, передаваемые на сервер (последний - подстрока для поиска):
      data:{
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 12,
        name_startsWith: request.term
      },
      // обработка успешного выполнения запроса
      success: function(data){
        // приведем полученные данные к необходимому формату и передадим в предоставленную функцию response
        response($.map(data.geonames, function(item){
          return{
            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
            value: item.name
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2
});
```